# How to access individual values from JWTAuth JSON data

Tags: php, json, laravel, jwt

I am attempting to extract JSON values from the return of a JWTAuth token 'user' key but cannot figure out how to address the inner keys using php.  I have the following code:

```
if(!$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()){
        abort(401);
    } 

    else{
        return response()->json(compact('user'));

    }
}
```

And when including the proper token in the header, I do receive the user info

```
{"user":{"id":2,"organization_name":"test corp","user_type":"administrator","created_at":"2016-05-13 17:26:20","updated_at":"2016-05-13 17:26:20","user_firstname":"Requester","user_lastname":"chester","user_emailaddress":"requester@test.com","remember_token":null,"user_id":"uid-7e3a0e15-c97b-44b1-885d-4370f4d1"}}
```

However, I cannot figure out a way to address the individual values of the keys inside of the "user" key.  How can I get the value of say the "user_firstname" key?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Using the Log::Info function within laravel to log data a local log. The following:

```
$json = response()->json(compact('user')); 
$arr = json_decode($json, true); 
Log::Info(var_dump($arr)); 
Log::Info($arr["user"]["user_firstname"]);
```

returns NULL for both the var dump and the multidimensional array call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to learn about json_encode and json_decode to convert json objects into an array and vice versa. See manual here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($array);
echo $array["user"]["user_firstname"];
```

Comment: Can you try Log::info('User logging in', ['id' => $arr['user']['id']]); then check storage/logs/* where the log will be recorded.

Comment: This was the solution. ['oid' => $user->organization_id] returns the organization ID of the specified user.  Thank you.

Comment: great! Im glad you got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $json = '{"user":{"id":2,"organization_name":"test corp","user_type":"administrator","created_at":"2016-05-13 17:26:20","updated_at":"2016-05-13 17:26:20","user_firstname":"Requester","user_lastname":"chester","user_emailaddress":"requester@test.com","remember_token":null,"user_id":"uid-7e3a0e15-c97b-44b1-885d-4370f4d1"}}';

 $arr = json_decode($json, true); //Converts JSON string into array

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($arr);
 echo "<pre>";
```

You could access array value :

```
 echo $arr["user"]["user_firstname"]; //Prints Requester
```